# ¿Cómo puedo manejar el evento TextChanged de un campo?

Tags: c#, array

Quiero buscar el Nombre desde la caja de TextBuscar pero me sale error ya que al recorrer con un for el buscar es igual a **"L"** y en el arreglo es **"Luis Pedro"** y no me deja escribir el nombre Completo ya que es un TextChanged y quiero aprender como utlizarlo.

Gracias si alguien me ayudara, soy nuevo en Programación.

*No hagáis caso a lo comentado, estaba practicando con clases y String[]*
**Y al botón Buscar**

```
 private void btnRgistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Persona per = new Persona();
            per.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
            per.Apellidos = txtApellidos.Text;
            per.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
            per.Fecha = txtFecha.Text;
            per.Cuidad = txtCiudad.Text;
            per.Estado = txtEstado.Text;


            //String[] per=new string[] {txtNombre.Text, txtApellidos.Text, txtSexo.Text,
                                       //txtFecha.Text,txtCiudad.Text, txtEstado.Text}; 

            listar(per);
        }

        public void listar(Persona p) {

            tablePersona.ColumnCount = 6;

            tablePersona.Columns[0].Name = "Nombre";
            tablePersona.Columns[1].Name = "Apellidos";
            tablePersona.Columns[2].Name = "Sexo";
            tablePersona.Columns[3].Name = "Fecha";
            tablePersona.Columns[4].Name = "Cuidad";
            tablePersona.Columns[5].Name = "Estado";

            tablePersona.Rows.Add(p.Nombre,p.Apellidos,p.Sexo,p.Fecha,p.Cuidad,p.Estado);

            //tablePersona.Rows.Add(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]);



            //int rowIndex = tablePersona.Rows.Add();
            //var row = tablePersona.Rows[rowIndex];

            //row.Cells[0].Value = p[0];
            //row.Cells[1].Value = p[1];
            //row.Cells[2].Value = p[2];
            //row.Cells[3].Value = p[3];
            //row.Cells[4].Value = p[4];
            //row.Cells[5].Value = p[5];

        }

//LO QUE QUIERO ENTENDER
private void txtBuscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string buscar;
            buscar = txtBuscar.Text;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                Persona p = new Persona();
                var agarrarNombre = tablePersona.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value;
                if (buscar !="")
                {
                    tablePersona.Rows.Add(p.Nombre[i],p.Apellidos[i], p.Sexo[i], p.Fecha[i], p.Cuidad[i], p.Estado[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: ERROR DESCRIPTION]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo muy bien donde quieres buscar, pero para empezar: estas tratando de acceder a `p.Nombre[i]`. `p` no tiene nada dado que acabas de crearlo dos lineas antes `Persona p = new Persona();`

Comment: Si eso lo vi y me esta devolviendo null, estoy averiguando en otro foros como utlizar el textChanged pero nada, lo que quiero es que en el textBox como ves en la imagen escribo L y ahi me sale el error y que en el table solo me muestre Luis Pedro y lo demás, lo que haria seria guardarlo en Un List<Persona> y llamar el método listar

Comment: Usar TextboxChanged es simple. se ejecutara cada vez que oprimas una tecla. Lo que tiene que hacer es ejecutar una consulta sobre ese evento y no lo estas haciendo ya que no veo que busques nada, solo quieres asignar un valor null. Segundo, creaste Persona que es un objeto sin array y le estas queriendo pasar una posicion de array.

Answer (score 1):

En el evento changed debes buscar sobre tu `array` o `List` por ejemplo. Puede ser una buena practica o no, hacer un `List<Persona>` nuevo porque te puede salir la excepcion que la coleccion a cambiado cuando quieras ingresar dos veces y detecte cambios.

```
    List<Persona> nuevaLista = new List<Persona>();
    List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>();


    private void txtBuscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string buscar;
        buscar = txtBuscar.Text;

        nuevaLista = personas.Where(x => x.Nombre.Contains(buscar)).ToList();
    }

   private void btnRgistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Persona per = new Persona();
        per.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
        per.Apellidos = txtApellidos.Text;
        per.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
        per.Fecha = txtFecha.Text;
        per.Cuidad = txtCiudad.Text;
        per.Estado = txtEstado.Text;


        //String[] per=new string[] {txtNombre.Text, txtApellidos.Text, txtSexo.Text,
                                   //txtFecha.Text,txtCiudad.Text, txtEstado.Text}; 

        personas.Add(per);
    }
```

Comment: Vale estoy entiendo, el "listar" donde lo declaro? en mi public void listar? tendria que modificarlo cierto?

Comment: el Listar, ya lo tenias declarado vos antes, entiendo que es una lista que accedes desde toda tu clase para agregar, borrar y buscar. Si la pregunta esta correcta y soluciono el problema. Marcala como tal.

Comment: Claro, pero recibe un valor de tipo Persona y al Llamarlo abajo me sale error

Comment: Que error? al llamarlo de donde?

Comment: El listar lo tenia declarado así Public void listar(**Persona p**){Consulte arriba } Al llamarlo abajo En nuevaLista=listar.where me sale el error ya que el VOID recibe de Persona p

Comment: ok, Lei mal el listar, lo confundi con un List<Persona>. tenes que agregar tus personas a una lista. Te edito la respuesta.